# How to listen the contents of div is being updated in vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a `list` created by `v-for` and wrapped by `md-scrollbar`.

```
<md-content class="md-scrollbar">
  <div v-for="(msg, index) of list" :key="index">
    {{msg}}
  </div>
</md-content>
```

After list changed, I wish the scrollbar scroll to the bottom.
So need to listen to element `updated` event or the scrollbar scrollHeight `changed` event. How to listen to certain DOM element's property is changed?

BTW I can't move the scroll after list changed logic because the new element hasn't been rendered at that moment yet, the height of `md-scrollbar` didn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need the updated dom, you could use [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) (after list data update) :

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
})
```

Comment: btw. in my case using in `.vue`, shall be `this.$nextTick(...)`

Answer (score 0):

use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) to watch `list` and react accordingly

e.g.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    c: {
        b: 2
    },
  },
  watch: {
    c: {
      handler: function(val, oldVal) {
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
});
```